# How can I deliver async integration testing using npm library?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, integration-testing, geojson

I maintain [a set of middleware](https://github.com/citygram/citygram-services) that is required to produce valid GeoJSON in order to power [its resulting service](http://citygram.org/).  There is an npm module that can perform the linting based on a String or object.  Since the middleware itself is not in node, I'd like to have a test-suite for the middleware that uses npm as an integration testing suite, ensuring that each endpoint is producing valid GeoJSON.

I am using mocha, but apart from that, I am open to any framework that produces results.  (I've tried Q, q-io, async-arrays, and a few others.)

Here's a synchronous-style writeup of what I'm aiming for:

```
describe('testPath()', function() {
    it("should be a function", function () {
      expect(geojsonLint.testPath).to.be.a('function')
    });

    it("should test a path", function () {
      var firstPath = geojsonLint.findEndpoints()[0];
      expect(geojsonLint.testPath(firstPath)).to.be.true
    });
});
```

Then, building on that, a synchronous version of testing all the paths might look like this:

```
describe('testAllPaths()', function() {
    it("should test a path", function () {
      geojsonLint.findEndpoints().map(function(path) {
         expect(geojsonLint.testPath(path)).to.be.true
      }
    });
});
```

I've altered my implementation of `testPath` significantly many times, but the most illustrative attempt is the following:

```
  testPath: function (path, callback) {
    return request('http://localhost:5000/'+path, function (error, response, body) {
      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        callback(geojsonhint.hint(body), error, response);
      } else {
        callback(body, error, response);
      }
    });
  }
```

I can ensure that the middleware is running locally on another port, in the event of a successful request, I'd like the results passed to geojsonhint.hint.  Ultimately, I'd like to verify the results of that call are empty.

My efforts so far are [available](https://github.com/citygram/citygram-services/pull/52), but I'd qualify them as poor.

Any fixed point on which to build is appreciated.

Comment: What exact question are you asking?  Your title is a very broad, non-specific question.  The rest of your question appears to be a description of  things you've done so far, but I can't find a specific, detailed question that fits the mold of the kind of things we answer here.

Comment: @jfriend00 thanks so much for looking it over anyway.

Answer (score 1):

With the existing implementation of testPath, [@rockbot](http://twitter.com/rockbot) was able to help me to this test invocation using mocha directly:

```
  it("should test a path", function (done) {
    var firstPath = geojsonLint.findEndpoints()[0];
    geojsonLint.testPath(firstPath, function(r, e, resp) {
      expect(r).to.be.empty;
      done();
    });
  });
```

Altering the signature of the test itself and invoking it from inside the callback worked!